# How to get the access for the identity platform users to acces the cloud function in GCP

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, gcp-iam

I'm  new to GCP, i found that identity platform is similar to cognito userpool in AWS. So that I have created few users in Identity platform (GCIP), able to authorize them with firebase script provided. I'm able to get the access token for the valid user present in Identity platform. By using that token I'm unable to access the Authorised cloud function.

Please suggest the steps to access the authorized cloud function for the users who are there in Identity platform.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an identity token not an access token.

See e.g. [Authenticating for Developer Testing](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#authenticating_developer_testing).

This is a little confusing with Google Cloud services where some accept access token and others require identity tokens.

Please include your attempts to solve a problem for yourself in your question. As you've seen, general "How do I?" questions will be downvoted and eventually closed.